# How to abandon session after changing <li> in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, session

This is my horizontal menu in ul il design. I have problem with converting my Login to Logout in the list.

```
<div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Dining.aspx">Dining</a></li>
            <li><a href="Meeting&Event.aspx">Meeting & Event</a></li>
            <li><a href="About_Us.aspx">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="Facilities.aspx">Facilities</a></li>
            <li><a href="Rooms.aspx">Rooms</a></li>
            <li><a href="Contact_Us.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li  style="float:right"><a id="aLogin" runat="server" href="Login.aspx">Login</a></li>
            <li id="liProfile" runat="server" style="float:right"><a href="GuestMenu.aspx">Profile</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

and this is on the .cs code under page load

```
if (Session["Username"] == null)
        {
            liProfile.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            string username = Session["Username"].ToString();
            aLogin.InnerText = "Logout";
            aLogin.Href = "Home.aspx";

        }
```

but the problem is that now how do i put Session.Abandon(); on the li of Logout now. So when the user see the Signout button, they can press it which abandon the session of the login. If possible, how do i put an OnClick event for href? so i can do an if statement for

```
if(aLogin.innerText == Logout) {
Session.Abandon();
}
else {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use 2 list itmes. One for login and one for logout.

```
<a href="/login.aspx" ID="aLogin" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Visible="False">Login</a>
<a href="/logout.aspx" ID="aLogout" Visible="False" EnableViewState="False" runat="server">Logout</a>
```

Then in the code behind:

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    aLogin.Visible = false;
    aLogout.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    aLogin.Visible = true;
    aLogout.Visible = false;
}
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**
You can use:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Comment: How does Request.IsAuthenticated work? Can i put Session.Abandon(); for Logout? does the visible changes after clicked? sorry for the noob question

Comment: Request.IsAuthenticated: Gets a value indicating whether the request has been authenticated. It's comes with ASP.NET. I guess that your session is abandoned if your Sesssion Username is "empty". The visibility changes after a successful login or logout (or session expired).